# How to execute SAP scheduled JOB via SAP .NET Connector

Tags: sap-basis, sap-dotnet-connector

I have some jobs scheduled on the SAP system. I want to execute the SAP jobs or modify the timings of the jobs. How can I execute the jobs.

I know how to connect to SAP system via .NET Connector.

```
        RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(rfcConfigParams);
        RfcRepository repository = dest.Repository;
        IRfcFunction rfcFunc = epository.CreateFunction("TH_GET_USER_LIST");
        fcFunc.Invoke(dest);
```

This way I can call the function module, but don't know how to call SAP jobs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a full API available to manage jobs externally. Look at function modules starting with "**BAPI_XBP_JOB**".

You can start a job with "**BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY**" or "**BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_ASAP**".

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complete Mikael answer. If you call `BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_ASAP` or any other XBP BAPI without first calling `BAPI_XMI_LOGON` (because XBP is an application of the "XMI family"), it returns a functional error in the parameter `RETURN`.

How it exactly works is [answered here in details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550714/9150270), in your on follow-up question.