# Getting "Not logged on in interface XBP" error when calling XBP function module via SAP .NET Connector

Tags: jobs, sap-basis, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I am getting the error while calling **BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY**

```
            IRfcFunction rfcFunc = repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_XMI_LOGON");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("extcompany", "testC");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("extproduct", "testP");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("interface", "XBP");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("version", "3.0");

            rfcFunc.Invoke(dest);

            rfcFunc = repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("jobname", "MYSCHEDULEDJOB");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("jobcount", "15530600");
            rfcFunc.SetValue("external_user_name", "username");

            rfcFunc.SetValue("target_server", "devsapsystem");
            rfcFunc.Invoke(dest);
```

The first function module is giving `sessionid` in output, but the second XBP call is giving the message

> Not logged on in interface XBP

Is there any problem parameters that I am passing or do I need maintain some session during these sequential calls?

Comment: Is this the entire code or did you omit some transaction handling code around this code block?

Comment: I haven't written any code for handling the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to execute the function calls in a single session (stateful mode). This is outlined in detail in the JCo documentation - basically you will have to wrap your logic into `JCoContext` method invocations like this:

```
try
{
  JCoContext.begin(destination); 
  try
  {
    // your function calls here
    // probably bapiTransactionCommit.execute(destination);
  }
  catch(AbapException ex)
  {
    // probably bapiTransactionRollback.execute(destination);
  } 
}
catch(JCoException ex)
{
  [...]
}
finally
{
  JCoContext.end(destination);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to call the above mentioned function call  with your suggested code, but it didn't work out too.
RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(destination);
// above BAPI calls 
RfcSessionManager.EndContext(destination);

Now I am getting different error "Internal problem (function BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY)".

Comment: You may need to debug the ABAP side in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you call `BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_ASAP` or any other XBP BAPI without first calling `BAPI_XMI_LOGON` (because XBP is an application of the "XMI family"), it returns a functional error in the parameter `RETURN`.

Note that this answer is not limited to SAP .NET Connector, the XBP BAPI can be run from any RFC-based client (JCo, NW RFC SDK, ABAP, SAP BC, SAP-GUI-integrated RFC client, pyRFC, etc.)

You must log into XMI via `BAPI_XMI_LOGON` with these input parameters:

- `EXTCOMPANY`: any name (your company name, no check)
- `EXTPRODUCT`: any name (your software name, no check)
- `INTERFACE`: the ID of the XMI application that you want to use ("XBP" in your case)
- `VERSION`: the version of the XMI application that you want to use (it could be "1.0", "2.0" or "3.0" for XBP, I recommend to use the latest version)

`BAPI_XMI_LOGON` returns these parameters:

- `SESSIONID`: an ID to be used if you need to call `BAPI_XMI_SELECT_LOG` to read the XMI log
- `RETURN`: error message if any

`BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_ASAP` and `BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY` **can run only an existing job (prepared in advance and waiting to be started)**. If you want to create your own job, call these BAPI:

- `BAPI_XBP_JOB_OPEN`: you pass a job name and it returns a "job count"
- Either `BAPI_XBP_JOB_ADD_ABAP_STEP` or `BAPI_XBP_JOB_ADD_EXT_STEP`
- `BAPI_XBP_JOB_CLOSE`

`BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_ASAP` and `BAPI_XBP_JOB_START_IMMEDIATELY` expect these input parameters:

- `JOBNAME`: the name of the job to start
- `JOBCOUNT`: the number of the job to start
- `EXTERNAL_USER_NAME`: any name
- etc.

Both return this parameter:

- `RETURN`: error message if any

Source: me + my own answer [at sap.com](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13803666/using-bapi-xbp-job-start-asap-doesnt-start-the-job.html).